# Prolog: Maplist appending results to main list instead of sublists

Tags: list, prolog, maplist

So I have the simple predicate defined as

```
pred(Info, List, Result) :-
  maplist(pred_calculate(Info), List, Result).
```

`pred_calculate` returns a list of X elements after an operation on a element of list, so for example `pred_calculate(Info, List, Result)` would return something like `[2,3,5]`

I want to add all the results of applying the `pred_calculate` predicate to all the elements of `List`, the problem I'm running into is that at the moment it's adding all the results from pred_calculate as sublists instead of adding to the single main list only.

So at the moment `Result` returns
`[[2,3,5],[5,7,8],[8,9,11]]` when it should return only `[2,3,5,5,7,8,8,9,11]`

How would I go about changing it to fix this behaviour?

Comment: flatten maybe your friend, or fold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `foldl/4` with `append/3`, you have to pass the arguments in the correct order to append, if the order of the items is important<sup>1</sup>:

```
pred(Info, List, Result) :-
    maplist(pred_calculate(Info), List, List1),
    foldl([A, B, C] >> append(B, A, C), List1, [], Result).
```

Also, `flatten/2` would achieve the same result, i.e.:

```
pred(Info, List, Result) :-
    maplist(pred_calculate(Info), List, List1),
    flatten(List1, Result).
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: `foldl(append, List1, [], Result)` would give you `[8,9,11,5,7,8,2,3,5]` as result.

Answer (score 1):

`maplist` calls `pred_calculate(Info)` on every corresponding element of `List` and `Result`. Perhaps `maplist` is not what you really want to use here if `pred_calculate` results in a list on each call since it's not a 1-1 correspondence. You have a 1-to-many and you want the many in one big, flat list. You could use `flatten` or `fold` as !joel76 suggests. Or, you could "manually" write your own `maplist`-like predicate which is very simple - just a basic list recursion and probably using append to achieve each step:

```
pred(Info, List, Result) :-
    pred(Info, List, [], Result).

pred(Info, [], Result, Result).
pred(Info, [H|T], Acc, Result) :-
    pred_calculate(Info, H, R),
    append(Acc, R, Acc1),
    pred(Info, T, Acc1, Result).
```